# GarageBand recording level stuck

Tags: garageband

I am recording an audio track in garageband 10.3.1..  I want to adjust the recording levels, and the slider is greyed out:

[image]

Why can't I slide it?  How can I adjust the volume?

Comment: Quit and reopen? Are you sure you have a mic connected?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I had already tried quitting and reopening. I had a mic connected, because I could record. The recording level was just too low. :/